# Как в sublime text 3 при помощи горячих клавиш расставить табы?

Tags: плагин, sublime-text-3

Как расставить все табы в html документе не вручную, а сочетанием клавиш в sublime text 3, например как это в Neatbeans - **alt+ctrl+f**. Есть ли плагины или эта функция встроенная уже в sublime?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь то от языка программирования и плагины разные на  форматирование кода. конкретно надо какой то ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://coderwall.com/p/7yxpdw/auto-indenting-on-sublime-text-3

Строку вставить в  "Key Bindings - User"

```
{"keys": ["alt+ctrl+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Comment: А это только на html или на css и jquery тоже?

Comment: Это стандр. функция в саблайне. везде можешь юзать

Comment: она находится в Edit->line->reindent